# Using heroku repo to reduce slug size but keep getting a "Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later." message

Tags: python, git, heroku, heroku-cli

We have been trying to deploy our Flask app using heroku but keep getting slug size too large errors that cause the build logs to fail.
In order to reduce the slug size, we have been trying to use heroku repo's `$ heroku repo:gc -a appname` and `$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname` commands, but we always get a
"Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later." message. We tried over several days and even tried creating new apps, but we still keep getting the [same error message.](https://camo.herokuusercontent.com/a895f3132ed6e619c8e1e93ce8c6abf770ddb5d6/68747470733a2f2f6865726f6b752d737570706f72742d70726f64756374696f6e2e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f63363134346662642d646466342d343738622d396131352d63313465663136623862646125324636326334316466612d393663622d346332392d396263632d3636356664316663343938322532466865726f6b75312e706e67)

We have been googling ways to reduce slug size but found that the best method is to use gc and purge_cache. Is there any other way to reduce the slug size?

[This is the GitHub repo we have been trying to deploy on heroku.](https://github.com/AEyeAlliance/web-application)

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm getting the same with `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: No, not yet. We contacted Heroku support but they closed the ticket saying that it was an application error issue. Did you manage to get it resolved?

Comment: In the end I had a few issues which, when resolved allowed me to get up and running. I didn't have the dj-static package installed locally so it was missing from my requirements.txt. I also had a typo in the Heroku settings in my settings.py

Answer (score -1):

This happens if you hit your free usage limit

Comment: I just created an account and it does the same thing, so I disagree !